Time machine transfer: Case Sensitive File systems
The goal is to migrate a user account from a BigSur MacBook to a Sonoma MacBook.   A SSD time machine backup was created last night.  Migration assistant was invoked and the SSD was selected:
The source is not using a Case Sensitive filesystem, while your Mac is.
The BigSur backup is greyed out,so I have "hit a wall".  I can select the backup however, the continue button remains grey / inoperable

What can be done to overcome this problem?  Do I have to reformat the new MacBook with a Case Insensitive version of APFS and then reinstall Sonoma? Or is there a work around?

Yes, you'll have to reformat as Case Insensitive.
Did you wipe the disk and reinstall the OS for some reason?
Normally, you shouldn't need to wipe and install, as the OS is on one disk volume, and "everything else" is on another. Just erasing the "everything else" volume is sufficient. You can do this in System Settings > General > Transfer or Reset.

Thank you.  I think you are indicating that it is necessary to reformat the new laptop's filesystem to case insensitive?  And then reinstall the OS / Apps.

@gatorback You may be able to change the format of only the Data volume, without wiping the whole thing.

Intriguing!  Is there an example online or would you consider adding the procedure to your answer?

Because Sonoma was just installed, I decided to reformat the drive to APFS (not case sensitive) and reinstall Sonoma.  I use a script to install apps via Homebrew, so it is automated.
